# Django Admin, Cuando creo un nuevo registro, me añade una columna llamada _order

Tags: django, django-admin

Llevo poco en Django y aún estoy acostumbrandome a su ORM, me ha surgido un problema y es:

Tengo dos modelos con una relación M2M y la tabla intermedia tiene un campo por lo que debo crear un modelo que haga de intermediario.

**product_catalog/models.py**

```py
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Product(models.Model):
    """
    Models an entertainment product
    """
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column="product_id")
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('service'), null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(_("Name"), max_length=255)
    profiles = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, verbose_name=_("profiles") ,through='ProfileProduct')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('product')
        verbose_name_plural = _('products')
        ordering = ('position', )
        managed = False
        db_table = 'products'

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class ProfileProduct(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column="profile_product_id")
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column="product_id", verbose_name=_("product"))
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column="profile_id", verbose_name=_("profile"))
    free_of_charge = models.BooleanField(_("Free?"), default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('profile using the product')
        verbose_name_plural = _('profiles using the product')
        managed = False
        db_table = 'profile_products'
        unique_together = (("product", "profile"),)
        order_with_respect_to = 'profile'
```

**customization/models.py**

```py
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Profile(models.Model):
    """
    Models a profile
    """
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column="profile_id")
    name = models.CharField(_("Name"), max_length=255)
    products = models.ManyToManyField('product_catalog.Product', through='product_catalog.ProfileProduct', verbose_name=_("products")) 


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('profile')
        verbose_name_plural = _('profiles')
        managed = False
        db_table = 'profiles'
```

Estos son los modelos relacionados entre ellos.

**product_catalog/admin.py**

```py
class ProfileProductsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ProfileProduct
    fields = ('profile', 'product', 'free_of_charge',)
    extra = 0
    can_delete = True

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(SortableAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = None
    inlines = [ProfileProductsInline,]
    list_display = ['name', 'service']
    list_display_links = ['name']
    list_filter = ['profiles', 'service']
    fields = ('name', 'service',) 
    ordering = ('service',)
```

Con todo esto consigo que en el admin pueda crear Productos y relacionarlos con perfiles, aparte añadiendo el campo de free_of_charge, el problema me viene cuando le doy a guardar dicho Producto que me sale el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado buscando y yo en ningún sitio tengo el campo "_order", las migraciones las tengo desactivadas así que no es un problema con el `makemigrations` y `migrate`

Comment: Creo que el problema es que no ejecutas las migraciones o algo así, pero dices que las "desactivaste"...

Comment: Si, desde el config.py, deshabilite los migrate y los makemigrations y si te fijas en class Meta: tengo managed = False, esto lo hago porque la BBDD está ya creada antes que el proyecto con Django